# Size of points determined by attribute value in SLD in GeoServer

Tags: qgis, geoserver, sld

I have a point layer with an attribute field containing decimal values. In QGIS, with the help of data defined overide I have managed to make the size of a point dependent on the value of a field (see picture below).

[image]

Now i want to emplement this in Geoserver through SLD

Is there a way to simply "call" the value of an object from a specific attribute field and bypass it to the <se:Size></se:Size> element?

Meaning if the value within a specified attribute field is 70,5 for for a point-object the value of <se:Size></se:Size> will be 70,5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any expression inside the size tag - in this case you want to use a `PropertyName` expression so something like:

```
<se:Size><ogc:PropertyName>myAttr</ogc:PropertyName></se:Size>
```

Comment: Absolutely Brilliant! That solution works. However, i have a follow-up question. Is it possible to multiply that value? As an example i want to pass <ogc:PropertyName>myAttr</ogc:PropertyName> and multiply it with 200. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, use `<ogc:mul>` - https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/filters.html#filter-expressions