# Width of lines determined by attribute value in SLD in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, line, sld

I read in [Size of points determined by attribute value in SLD in Geoserver](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394420/size-of-points-determined-by-attribute-value-in-sld-in-geoserver), that it is possible to set the size of points via an attribute supplied by the data source as follows:

```
<se:Size><ogc:PropertyName>myAttr</ogc:PropertyName></se:Size>
```

I want to do the same thing, but using lines, and setting the thickness/width of the lines based on an attribute from the data source. LineSymbolizer does not have the `<size>` tag that can be found in PointSymbolizer.

Is there a way to use a data source attribute/column to set the width of the line dynamically?

**EDIT:**
Soon after I posted this question, I started testing, and realized that all I had to do was to add a PropertyName tag with the data source column name, inside the CssParameter with the stroke-width name attribute:

```
<CssParameter name="stroke-width">
    <ogc:PropertyName>_flow_width</ogc:PropertyName> 
</CssParameter>
```

I see now that @Ian Turton also suggested it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the `<CssParameter name="stroke-width">6</CssParameter>` to change the width of your line.

It's always worth having a peruse of the [SLD Cookbook](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/) to see what can be done or even read the [actual documentation for a feature](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/linesymbolizer.html).

Comment: I understand the standard setting of stroke-width when you know beforehand what that width must be, but when the width can be anything, then I need to set that width dynamically according to a width provided in the data source.

Comment: so put an `<ogc:PropertyName>" in there as you did in your question